# Editing answers to remove "signatures"

Tags: discussion

I came across this post yesterday:

https://music.stackexchange.com/a/52367

The answer is fine, and contains reasonable content; however, it includes a signature with a link to the author's web site. The link is unrelated to the contents of the post.

I initially edited the post to remove the signature; the rest of the content was fine, and isn't spam. However, the link has since been edited back in.

What's the correct approach here? I could flag as spam, but the post isn't really spam? I could raise a generic flag? Or I could edit it again, but edit wars are something I avoid. Or I could just leave it alone; it's not really hurting anyone, I guess. How do we normally deal with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our official stance is [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> #### Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card,
> which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional
> signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the
> questions and answers.
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your
> interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

It's not a high priory, but they should be removed. In general try to explain either in the edit summary or a comment on the post. If there are edit conflicts and rollbacks happening you can flag it for moderator attention with the custom flag with an explanation and we can take a look.

Comment: Ah, that's where it was hiding. Sounds pretty much as I thought. Thanks.